# Hang when executing play Command

Tags: playframework

I am currently learning java Play Framework by following the online tutorial. 
Every thing is fine until i type in 'Play' Command in the console.

The console is constantly reporting Server Access Error: Operation Timeout as the following. I am pretty sure that i have connected to the Internet.

```
    [info] Loading project definition from /Users/ruanpingcheng/Desktop/myFirstApp/project
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-  releases/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe/config/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.google.javascript/closure-compiler/v20130603/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.json/json/20090211/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/net.contentobjects.jnotify/jnotify/0.94/ivys/ivy.xml
    [error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.5.1/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Could any one to help me to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting one of the URLs into your browser and see if it gets the XML file:

http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe/config/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml

If your browser can't access the file, then its an issue with your network or internet provider.